# Google react maps - how to change control color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use `google-react-maps` with `zoomControl` and `mapTypeControl`:

[image]

```
  <Map onMount={(map, maps) => {}} {...mapProps} style={{
      height: '100%'
    }} api-key={key} optionsConstructor={(maps) => {
      return {
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        keyboardShortcuts: true,
        mapTypeId: maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
          position: maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
        },
        scaleControl: true,
        rotateControl: true,
        rotateControlOptions: {
          position: maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
          position: maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP             
        }
      }
    }}>
```

How to change zoom and map type controls background color?

Comment: You can't. Create your own [custom controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) if you want to have full control over the appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just target the element then add a CSS background color (div > div > div > button). You can be more specific by using classes in css instead of the element. Here's what I did (check the CSS codes):

```js
function initMap(){
  var radius = 10000;
  var latlng = {lat:47.423201, lng:-120.311193};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: latlng,
    streetViewControl:  false,
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

```css
#map{
   height:50%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div > div > div > button { /* this is what I did */
  background-color: red !important
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>   
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's a working sample: http://jsbin.com/cosezum/edit?html,css,js,output

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

## If you are using Tailwind

If you are using tailwind you can add this to the `Map`s parent or `Map` itself: `[&_.gm-control-active]:!bg-neutral-800`.

## Note

1. The exclamation mark is important since zoom control buttons usually have inline styles.
2. Remember that this will change the color of the `+` and `-` images as well. since they are transparent images.
3. There is a separator between the `+` and `-` buttons. You can get rid of them with adding these 2 in your `className` but the drawback is that it will also changes the color of the copyright section:

   ```
   "[&>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div]:!bg-red-500",
   "[&>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div>div]:!bg-transparent",
   ```

## Customized zoom control for you google map in react

In general I think the best course of action would be to just disable the zoom control all together and build it from scratch as you like:

1. Pass `zoomControl: false` to
2. ```
   <button className="somthing" onClick={() => map?.setZoom(Number(map.getZoom()) + 1)}>+</button>
   <button className="somthing" onClick={() => map?.setZoom(Number(map.getZoom()) - 1)}>-</Button>
   ```